# Laravel , how to select data if relationship condition is true

Tags: php, jquery, laravel, model-view-controller, laravel-5

i have this query

```
$organisationUserNotifications = OrganisationUserNotification::
            whereHas('user',function($user){
                $user->where('status',STATUS_ACTIVE);
            })
            ->orWhere('new_comment',ORGANISATION_NOTIFICATION_ACTIVE)
            ->orWhere('new_review',ORGANISATION_NOTIFICATION_ACTIVE)
            ->orWhere('new_salary',ORGANISATION_NOTIFICATION_ACTIVE)
            ->get();
```

this query get result for all users who have `new_comment->1` or `new_review->1` or `new_salary->1`

i have `user` table

> `id` `name` `status`
>    `1`| `us_1`| `0` 
>    `2`| `us_2`| `1` 
>    `3`| `us_3`| `1`

and `notification` table

> `id` `new_comment` `new_review` `new_salary`
>    `1`| `0`| `1` | `1`
>    `2`| `1`| `0` | `1`
>    `3`| `1`| `0` | `1`

this query get all rows because user 1 have `status` 0 or `new_review` 1
please any idea
how to verify other `where` if user is active , without leftjoin

Answer (score 0):

ok , i found the solution if anyone needs it

```
$organisationUserNotifications = OrganisationUserNotification::
        whereHas('user',function($user){
            $user->where('status',STATUS_ACTIVE);
        })
        ->where(function($query){
           $query->orWhere('new_comment',ORGANISATION_NOTIFICATION_ACTIVE);
           $query->orWhere('new_review',ORGANISATION_NOTIFICATION_ACTIVE);
           $query->orWhere('new_salary',ORGANISATION_NOTIFICATION_ACTIVE);
        })
        ->get();
```